# Appending to gzip file in Python doesnt work

Tags: python, io, gzip

I have following function :

```
def save(msg):
    with gzip.open("ircbot.log.gz", "ab") as f:
        f.write(msg+'\n')
        f.close()
        return "Succesfully logged: "+msg
```

I want to add each msg to .log file but it doesnt work, only first msg is saved.

For example after calling those functions :

```
save('first')
save('second')
save('third')
```

.log file contains only 'first'.

For simple .txt file it works fine. Gzip doesn't support appending to file?

Comment: NB you don't need to/shouldn't call `close` when using files as context managers.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I run your function (after fixing the obvious syntax error in the first line), I get exactly the desired behavior. The syntax error suggests that this is not your actual code.

Comment: I copyed just function logic. I added the function name to demonstrate calling it thats why I forgot about ':'.

Comment: @delnan Calling a GzipFile object’s close() method does not close fileobj,... --python.org; so here it doesn't actually matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenating gzip streams to make an extractable gzip file (i.e. `f.close()` after each message) *does* work, as you discovered.  This is because the gzip standard requires a compliant decompressor to look for another gzip stream after it decodes the current one.  However, assuming that your messages are relatively short, e.g. a line or two, then the resulting gzip file will be larger, not smaller than a simple text file with the messages.  Each message will have at least the overhead of a gzip header and trailer of 18 bytes, and the data will likely expand by five bytes, adding 23 bytes per message.

The alternative of not using `f.close()` after each message will result in real compression of the data, by writing a single gzip stream where the compression of later messages can take advantage of redundancy with earlier messages.  However this has the downside of never having a complete and correct gzip file until you *do* finally call `f.close()`.  In addition, messages will not be written at all (again if they are short), until enough have been accumulated to compress a block.  Then a bunch will be written in a burst, and the file will wait again for more to be accumulated.

There is a solution to this, but I don't think python has a complete enough interface to zlib to permit it.  You can look at an example in C, [gzlog.h](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [gzlog.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c), which writes log entries to a gzip file immediately, and always leaves the log file in a complete and correct state.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

I used Altap Salmander to extract .gz and view log file (F3 function).

When I extracted gz file in classic explorer with 7zip all msgs were there.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, without the extra `f.close()`, Linux, python-2.7, both with gzip file created by this script and a gzip file created by regular gzip command.